# Was planning to visit family in the UK for 2 weeks; what can I do about this refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

> **REASONS FOR REFUSAL**
>   You have applied for a visa to visit the UK.
>   In deciding whether you meet the requirements of Appendix V: of the Immigration Rules for visitors (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitorrules), I have considered:
>
> - your application and any additional relevant information you have
>     provided with it
> - your immigration history
>
> The decision
>   I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph 4.2 of Appendix V because:
>
> - You are applying to come to the UK with for 2 weeks. I note that this
>     will be your first trip to the UK. You state that you are employed,
>     where you earn £1,257.62 per month, you have savings of £7000.6, and
>     you intend to spend £1,000.00 on your trip to the UK.
> - In support of your application, you have provided an employment
>     letter, payslips and a bank statement, and you have explained the
>     cash deposits credited to your account. However, the information you
>     have provided does not satisfactorily demonstrate your monthly
>     outgoings, or explain how the bank balance has escalated in a short
>     period of time. I am therefore not satisfied that these funds are
>     available to you for your personal use.
> - Given the above, I am not satisfied by your intentions in wishing to
>     travel to the United Kingdom for a limited period, or that you will
>     leave the UK at the end of your visit.
>
> Furthermore, I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in the UK without working or accessing public funds. Your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) (c) and (e) of the Immigration Rules.
>
> In relation to this decision, there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review

Comment: See [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), particularly the section on 'Funds Parking, Lifestyle, and Credibility'.

Comment: @John Scott The answer to what you can do is in the refusal letter - provide more bank statements (minimum 6 months is typical) to demonstrate your monthly outgoings, and explain (and provide evidence for) how your bank balance escalated rapidly. If you can’t do that, you’d be wasting your time and money if you reapply.